# Freemarker: read some template parameters programmatically

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to read some freemarker template values programmatically from Java as follows:

```
public Map<String, Object> getRootAssignments() {
    Enumeration en = template.getRootTreeNode().children();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object next = en.nextElement();

        // instanceof private class does not work
        if (next.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Assignment")) {
            map.put(getInternalState(next, "variableName").toString(), 
                    getInternalState(next, "value").toString());
        }
    }
    return map;
}



private Object getInternalState(Object o, String fieldName) {
    Field field = null;
    boolean wasAccessible = false;
    try {
        field = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        wasAccessible = field.isAccessible();
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    } finally {
        if (field != null) {
            field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
        }
    }
}
```

With this I can easily read `<#assign variable = "value"/>`. But once I need to get some variable which needs to be evaluated (for instance `<#assign variable = "first" + "second"/>`), this obviously does not work.

In fact I don't really like this approach, I would prefer to read the variable states AFTER the template rendering, so nothing would have to be evaluated again. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read back variable values if you keep the `freemarker.core.Environment` alive, like this:

```
Environment env = myTemplate.createProcessingEnvironment(root, out);
env.process();  // process the template
TemplateModel x = env.getVariable("x");
```

As of your initial approach, note that you are using API-s that were marked is internal, means no long term backward compatibility guarantees. But what's really brittle is reading private fields with reflection. Then calling `TemplateObject.getParameterCount`/`getParameterRole`/`getParameterValue` is more stable, as that's at least an API, even if internal.